# How to configure php's "array_rand" to not give 2 same results on after another?

Tags: php, arrays, random

I use php `array_rand` to select 1 random record from array, Example:

```
$style_class = array("st_style1","st_style2","st_style3","st_style4");
$random_class = array_rand($style_class, 1);
$div_class = $style_class[$random_class];
```

The issue is that sometimes it gives a same record several times, and as I use only 4 records it happens quiet often (using "array_rand" is not neccesary) .

Example:

st_style1,
**st_style2,
st_style2,
st_style2,**
st_style4,
st_style2 ...

Is there a way to solve this issue, so two same record would not get displayed two times in a row.

For example

st_style2, st_style4, st_style2, st_style1, st_style3, st_style2, st_style1 ...

Comment: repeating sequences are part of randomness. It's highly unlikely, but you can get heads a billion times in a row on a coin toss. Doesn't look random, but is possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simpliest solution is to keep track of the latest one and keep calling random until you get something different.  Something like:

```
$style_class = array("st_style1","st_style2","st_style3","st_style4");
$styles = array()
$lastStyle = -1
for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
    while(1==1) {
        $newStyle = array_rand($style_class, 1);
        if ($lastStyle != $newStyle) { 
            $lastStyle = $newStyle;
            break;
        }
    }
    $div_class = $style_class[$lastStyle]
    $styles[] = $div_class
}
```

Then use the `$styles[]` array in order.  It should not have any duplicates

Comment: so in this case, I would use $lastStyle instead of $div_class if I use your code right?

Comment: Tried it out, seems to work, but still sometimes I get same record twice or even more :/ -- code I use -- $style_class = array("st_style1","st_style2","st_style3","st_style4");
  $lastStyle = -1;
        while(1==1) {
        $newStyle = array_rand($style_class, 1);
          if ($lastStyle != $newStyle) { 
             $lastStyle = $newStyle;
             break;
      }
  }
  $div_class = $style_class[$lastStyle];

Comment: Doesn't this defeat the idea of 'random'?

Comment: I edited it again to show the full code.  After running this, you'll get all of the styles you want. Just change the 5 to however many you need.

Answer (score 2):

Basically same as [James J. Regan IV's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7839264/how-to-configure-phps-array-rand-to-not-give-2-same-results-on-after-another/7839334#7839334), but using a [*do-while* loop](http://php.net/control-structures.do.while):

Set up the array like this:

```
$style_class = array("st_style1","st_style2","st_style3","st_style4");
$prev_class = -1;
```

And then, to obtain a random class:

```
do {
    $random_class = array_rand($style_class, 1);
} while ($random_class == $prev_class);
$div_class = $style_class[$prev_class = $random_class];
```

---

**Edit:** Alternative solution, with no loops:

```
$style_class = array("st_style1","st_style2","st_style3","st_style4");
$random_class = array_rand($style_class);
```

To obtain a new random class:

```
$random_class += rand(1, count($style_class)-1);
$div_class = $style_class[$random_class % count($style_class)];
```

This works as long as the array keys are consecutive integers starting from zero (as is the case if you define it with `array()` and don't explicitly specify any keys).

Answer (score 1):

Save the last style in a var, then make a loop till the new style differs from last style. And then you will have a different from the last on every execution.